# How do I get the Http error codes using OkHttp3

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using OkHttp3 in my Android app.
My problem is that the only response that returns correctly is 200. All others raise an exception.
Is there any way to prevent it raising the exceptionand to get the response code.

This is my code:

```
        try {
        val network: Network? = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
        val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
        val httpBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(100000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(100000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .socketFactory(network!!.socketFactory)
        val okHttpClient = httpBuilder.build()

        val request = Request.Builder().url(urlString).build()

        okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute().use {response ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Network response: ${response.networkResponse}")
            httpRequestResult.onSuccess(response.networkResponse.toString())

    } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SocketTimeoutException: ${e}")
    }catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: ${e}")
    }
```

I am using the socketFactory because I want to make sure it uses the wifi connection even if the mobile data is also on.

Can this be done or is my approach completely wrong.

Comment: What kind(s) of exception? Tell us the exception message. You log it. Use it.

Comment: For example: Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to ..... As can see, there is no response code to explain what happened.

Comment: Of course not. The exception tells you all: failed to connect. If there is no connection established them the server can send nothing. No result code can be send as the server does not even know that your app tried to connect.

Comment: How were you testing for other HTTP status codes, since, like others have said above, `ConnectException` will happen only if the connection fails, meaning there couldn't have been a response at all. On properly established connection and successful request, you can retrieve code using `.code()` method or `code` property.

Answer (score 0):

1. Catch a more generic IOException instead of the specific SocketTimeoutException. This will cover other IO-related exceptions.
2. Use response.code() to retrieve the HTTP status code.

```
try {
    val network: Network? = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
    val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
    val httpBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(100000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .readTimeout(100000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .socketFactory(network!!.socketFactory)
    val okHttpClient = httpBuilder.build()

    val request = Request.Builder().url(urlString).build()

    okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
        val statusCode = response.code()
        Log.d(TAG, "HTTP Status Code: $statusCode")

        // Handle response based on status code
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            // Process successful response
            val responseBody = response.body()?.string()
            Log.d(TAG, "Response Body: $responseBody")
            httpRequestResult.onSuccess(responseBody)
        } else {
            // Process unsuccessful response
            val errorBody = response.body()?.string()
            Log.d(TAG, "Error Body: $errorBody")
            httpRequestResult.onFailure("HTTP Status Code: $statusCode, Error Body: $errorBody")
        }
    }
} catch (e: IOException) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IOException: $e")
}
```

Comment: Problem is that if the response isn't 200 I never get into that code. It always throws and exception. For example: Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to .....

Comment: catch (e: ConnectException) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: $e")
    // Handle connection failure specifically
} try that